# Which thread acquires lock on which object?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I am a newbie to java and I am really confused with the lock acquired by the threads. I really didn't get, whether the caller object gets locked or the called object gets locked??

For example:

```
public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    Demo demo = new Demo();
    public void run() {
        demo.setX();
    }
} 

class Demo {

   private synchronized void setX(){
      System.out.println("hello"); 
   }
}
```

So, here does the object referred by the reference **'demo'** gets locked?

or

the instance of the class **'ThreadB'** gets locked??

Comment: The instance of `Demo` - because you're calling a synchronized instance method in `Demo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance of class Demo called demo gets locked.
synchronized methods are confusing.  I think in most cases it is better to use explicit lock objects, e.g.

```
private void setX(){
   System.out.println("hello");
   synchronized (this) {
      this.x = 42;
      this.y = 37;
   }
   System.out.println("bye");
}
```

Comment: A synchronized instance method uses 'this' as the lock object, while a synchronized static method uses the class instance (aka: this.getClass()) as the lock object.

Comment: by 'explicit lock' do you mean the 'synchronized blocks'?

Comment: yes, or one of the "new" java.util.concurrent lock objects, e.g. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html